# How to pass parameters to MiniTest::Unit::TestCase suite?

Tags: ruby, rake, minitest

I'm using an external API that takes a key string, and would like to pass this key string to the test suite. Something like:

```
rake test [key=api_key]
```

The code together with the tests will be open sourced, but I'm not allowed to distribute  my key string to other users, so I cannot put it in the test file. Can I pass it as a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options. Pass it as an environment variable:

```
API_KEY='key' rake test
```

You can then access this through the ENV object in your test:

```
key = ENV['API_KEY']
```

Second option is to put this key in a file (e.g. key.txt) and you read it from that. To ensure that you don't distribute that file with your code, add it to your .gitignore file (or whatever is the ignore file used by your SCM)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much!

I actually was thinking of putting it into a file and gitignoring it, but ended up passing a parameter to rake. May be, I will combine both (it's a long key).

1. Modify the Rakefile code for the :test task, such as adding a
   parameter to it.

   > ```
   > task :test, :key do |t, k|
   >   result = system("ruby -Ilib -Itest -e 'ARGV.each { |f| load(f) if File.exists?(f)}' test/unit/* '#{k[:key]}'")
   >   exit(result ? 0 : 1)
   > end
   > ```
2. Call rake test['blah-blah']

It may take more then one key if needed.